# Threaded result not giving same result as un-threaded result (python)

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I have created a program to generate data points of functions that I later plot. The program takes a class which defines the function, creates a data outputting object which when called generates the data to a text file. To make the whole process faster I put the jobs in threads, however when I do, the data generated is not always correct. I have attached a picture to show what I mean:

[image: Data Plot]

Here are some of the relevant bits of code:

```py
from queue import Queue
import threading
import time

queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = Queue(10) 

def process_data(threadName, q, queue_window, done):
    while not done.get():
        queueLock.acquire()         # check whether or not the queue is locked
        if not workQueue.empty():
            data = q.get()
            # data is the Plot object to be run
            queueLock.release()
            data.parent_window = queue_window
            data.process()
        else:
            queueLock.release()
        time.sleep(1)

class WorkThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, q, done):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ID = threadID
        self.q = q
        self.done = done
    def get_qw(self, queue_window):
        # gets the queue_window object
        self.queue_window = queue_window
    def run(self):
        # this is called when thread.start() is called
        print("Thread {0} started.".format(self.ID))
        process_data(self.ID, self.q, self.queue_window, self.done)
        print("Thread {0} finished.".format(self.ID))

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, etc):
        self.threads = []
        # does some things
    def makeThreads(self):
        for i in range(1, int(self.threadNum.get()) +1):
            thread = WorkThread(i, workQueue, self.calcsDone)
            self.threads.append(thread)
    # more code which just processes the function etc, sorts out the gui stuff.
```

And in a separate class (as I'm using tkinter, so the actual code to get the threads to run is called in a different window) (self.parent is the Application class):

```py
    def run_jobs(self):
        if self.running == False:
            # threads are only initiated when jobs are to be run
            self.running = True
            self.parent.calcsDone.set(False)
            self.parent.threads = []        # just to make sure that it is initially empty, we want new threads each time
            self.parent.makeThreads()
            self.threads = self.parent.threads

            for thread in self.threads:
                thread.get_qw(self)
                thread.start()

            # put the jobs in the workQueue
            queueLock.acquire()
            for job in self.job_queue:
                workQueue.put(job)
            queueLock.release()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Jobs already running")
```

This is all the code which relates to the threads.
I don't know why when I run the program with multiple threads some data points are incorrect, whilst running it with just 1 single thread the data is all perfect. I tried looking up "threadsafe" processes, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`? If your work is mostly CPU- and not IO-bound, then I think you did.

Comment: It looks like access to `queue_window` is not thread-safe. Is it supposed to be?

Comment: @WaleedKhan: When I was originally learning how to do threads the tutorial used threading, only more recently did I find out about multiprocessing, but I wasn't sure if I had to change to that for it to work, or whether this method should still work?

Comment: @matt_sanderson The method should still work, but due to the Global Interpreter Lock it [might actually be slower than serial processing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3121109/344643). But first I'd worry about fixing your thread-safety, of course, since switching to `multiprocessing` won't fix that.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, It does seem to not be any faster. Is there some way to actually fix the thread-safety?

Comment: @matt_sanderson Can you say whether or not access `queue_window` is thread-safe?

Comment: The queue_window object is a Toplevel object in tkinter, so I am assuming probably not?