# Time Comparison Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a program that reads some input text files and write all of them into one separate file. I used two threads so it runs faster!
I tried the following python code with both one thread and two threads! Why when I run with one thread it runs faster than when I run it with two threads?

```html
processedFiles=[]
# Define a function for the threads
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
      #check if file has been read by another thread already 
      if file not in processedFiles:
         processedFiles.append(file)
         f = open(file,"r")
         lines = f.readlines()
         f.close()
         time.sleep(delay)
         f = open('myfile','a')
         f.write("%s \n" %lines) # python will convert \n to os.linesep
         f.close() # you can omit in most cases as the destructor will call it
         print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

   
# Create two threads as follows
try:
   f = open('myfile', 'r+')
   f.truncate()

   start = timeit.default_timer()

   t1 = Thread(target=print_time, args=("Thread-1", 0,))
   t2 = Thread(target=print_time, args=("Thread-2", 0,))
   t1.start()
   t2.start()


   stop = timeit.default_timer()

   print stop - start

except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python threading unexpectedly slower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121109/python-threading-unexpectedly-slower)

Comment: In Python, more threads != more speed. Pure Python bytecode cannot run concurrently, even using multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems I'll get to in a moment, but generally your program is disk-bound (it can't go faster than your hard drive) so even a properly threaded program isn't any faster. It can be hard to measure disk performance because of the file system cache: You run this once with threads and you go at hard drive speed, you run it again without threads and the files are in the system so go fast. It makes it hard to figure out how the code will perform later when the data no longer in the system cache.

So now for the problems.

`if file not in processedFiles:` isn't thread safe. Both threads could look at an empty list and decide to copy the same file. At a minimum you need a lock. Or you could do the `glob` once and pass the files to a queue that are read by the thread.

Reading the file line-by-line then joining with `\n` is a crazy slow way to write a file. Use `shutil.copyfileobj` instead - its built to copy files efficiently.

`f = open('myfile','a')` now you have multiple file descriptors to a single file and each will advance their file pointers independently.... so one overwrites the other.

`f.write("%s \n" %lines)` is also not thread safe. You could end up with bits of the files interleaving each other in the output file.

`stop = timeit.default_timer()` - you didn't wait for the threads to complete their work so you didn't really measure anything useful. Code code severely under-reports execution time.

You are much better off with a simple single-threaded script.